# CertOpenStore access denied

Tags: c++, certificate

I have a pice of code in c++ that gets certificate from store:

```
// Open CA system store
m_hCertStore = ::CertOpenStore(
    CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM, 
    0,
    NULL, 
    CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
   //CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    Store
);

if( !m_hCertStore )
    throw MY_WIN32_TO_HRESULT(GetLastError());

// Locate "iScala License Key Generator" certificate
m_pCCertContext = ::CertFindCertificateInStore(
    m_hCertStore, 
    PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING, 
    0, 
    CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR, 
    CertSubject, 
    NULL
);
```

When it tries to open the Cert Store I get an access denied error.

The certificate is in the Certificates/Current User, Intermediate Certification Authorities.

Comment: Have you tried to open it as read-only? CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER|CERT_STORE_READONLY_FLAG